# app in kiosk mode on android

Tags: android

I am looking for a possibility to start an app in kiosk mode. I want a flash / air application on android 2.2 100. tablets distributed.

nice it would be even if there is a possibility that this will start fullscreen app directly.

regards

Comment: i want to distribute only one air/flash app on 100+ tablets. when the tablets starts, the app start fullscreen.

Comment: you don't need to build a custom firmware, you need to build a custom launcher.

Comment: Could you provide more detail? Maybe a tutorial on how to create a launcher?

Answer (score 2):

Cant say about the exact implementation, but definitely it possible to achieve this without creating custom firmware or rooting the device.

This app on market [SureLock](http://www.42gears.com/surelock/) claims to run the device in kiosk mode and is available for android 2.2. Doesn't require any root permissions i guess.

Its discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625413/is-it-posible-to-use-a-device-to-run-one-application-exclusively). As per their description, they have run at start-up and full-screen support. So either u can use this app or figure out how these gyus have done it. good luck.

Comment: Any hints about how surelock remove home button? I would like to do it within my app. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to create your own custom firmware. There is seems no other way to enforce kiosk mode. Please take a look at this question - [Kiosk mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android) and this one as well [Is it possible to create an android app to make the phone run in sort of a kiosk mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881373/is-it-possible-to-create-an-android-app-to-make-the-phone-run-in-sort-of-a-kiosk)

Comment: how can I create a custom firmware? perhaps someone can do this for  me?

Comment: No one's gonna do it for you *for free* but I'm sure there are freelance ROM developers out there who might be interested in a job offer. Note that this is non-trivial work and might take several months of paid time to get it to a usable level.