# How to override Task Manager in android

Tags: android, taskmanager

Is it possible to override the functionality of Task manager in android like preventing the app to be open from task manager. I searched in net but i didn't find any answer.

I installed an app from market named surelock. In that app they have override the taskmanager. How it is posssible

sivakumar

Comment: @PC, if you are going to create a self-promotional tag, at least be less obvious about it by adding it only to *relevant* questions.  You should do the community a favor by also *answering* relevant questions, such as this one.

Comment: But I'm not creating any promotion tags. Infact, such questions has been asked several times on stackoverflow and has been answered too. I'm just tagging them so that others can find such solutions easily.

Comment: by the way, you can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10713550/925202

Comment: @PC: Yes you are. You're tagging questions about *your own product* in bulk. That reeks of promotion. You should not tag a question if the question has nothing to do with the product. In fact, just stop using the tag. There is no need for it.