# Set Custom call activity

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I would like to set my own activity infront the call screen. I have seen that there are many examples for this but with the older versions of android, while I want it to work with android 6.0 and above. This means that I have to deal with the permissions. I managed to grant the necessary permissions. After that I make a Class that inherits `BroadcastReceiver` so that I can detect when the phone is ringing, the only problem is that I can't send my activity infront of the call display. These are some of the classes I use:

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Receiver start");
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            Toast.makeText(context, " Receiver start ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing State Number is -", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(context, LockActivity.class);
                dialogIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                context.startActivity(dialogIntent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class LockActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_screen);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                +WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                +WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        Button btnLock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUnlock);
        final EditText txtPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
        btnLock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String pass = txtPass.getText().toString();
                if(pass.equals("pass")||pass.equals("пасс")) {
                    finish();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LockActivity.this, "Wrong password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

If anything else is needed please ask!

Comment: maybe this older post on creating a [Custom Android Telephony application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600377/custom-android-telephony-application) is useful?

Comment: No, the link is leading to an old question with links that are no longer available

Comment: That's a pity, the collection of links looked promising. Did I at least get you right and you want to write a "Phone app"?

Comment: Just an app that locks the screen when receiving a call.

Comment: Then sorry for bothering you. And good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it, the problem is that it takes time to start the in-built call activity, so my activity started first and the other went on top of it. Therefore I made the current thread of my activity to sleep for less than a second. The in-built activity was launched and then my activity went on top of it.

```
 public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Receiver start");
                String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                Toast.makeText(context, " Receiver start ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing State Number is -", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(context, LockActivity.class);
                    dialogIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                    Thread.sleep(700);
                    context.startActivity(dialogIntent);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```